# Datasnap Client/Server 32/64

Tags: delphi, client-server, datasnap

I have a problem with datasnap in delphi Xe3.

At server side I create an application that load data from an XML file in a clientdataset and shares it through a datasetprovider.
The Client has a clientdataset that load data into a grid.

It works fine if Server and Client run both at 32 or 64 bit, but if I try to run the Server at 32 bit and the Client at 64 or viceversa the Client can't insert or delete a record and it gives an exception (Access violation).

Thanks for reply.

Tarroni Andrea.

Comment: Could you step on the Client side with the debugger and see where it does trigger the access violation? (using RTL in debug mode) Perhaps there is some encoding issue.

Comment: I've tried to debug the Client side and I arrive into file "canex.cpp" in the function "QFetchValue" where it does trigger the access violation.